# how do i print the index of a value with letters in a string in python?

Tags: python, string, list

I have:

*MONTHS = ("January", "February", "March", ... "December") (all months included)

I'm supposed to input the 3 letter abbreviation for a month and get the index value for the month. So far, I have:

```
for M in MONTHS:
    shortMonths = M[0:3]
    print shortMonths
```

> Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec

I noticed that the output months in shortMonths do not have quotation marks, which is making it impossible to test if an abbreviation is in shortMonths:

> MMM = "Feb"
>
> print list(shortMonths).index(MMM) + 1 # taking into consideration that the first month of the list, January, is month 0+1 = 1 and so on for all months
>
> > > ValueError: 'Feb' is not in list

How can I fix this without creating a function? 
Also, this is an assignment question. And, we're not allowed to use dictionaries or maps or datetime

Comment: Try `print 'hi'` in your interpreter and the Mystery of the Missing Quotation Marks may become solved.

Comment: This is not a real Python question... more about programming in general (i.e. what 'print' means!). I suggest to start learning how to debug your program so that you will be able to find mistakes and learn from them.

Comment: @roippi, `the Mystery of the Missing Quotation Marks` is cool :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you want `shortMonths` to be a list, but you're just assigning a string to it.

I think you want something like this:

```
shortMonths = [] # create an empty list
for M in MONTHS:
    shortMonths.append(M[0:3]) # add new entry to the list
print shortMonths # print out the list we just created
```

Or using a *list comprehension*:

```
# create a list containing the first 3 letters of each month name
shortMonths = [M[0:3] for M in MONTHS]
print shortMonths # print out the list we just created
```

Comment: Points out the OP's misunderstanding.  Gives a pointer to list comp.  +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

shortMonths is string not a list. Do as below.

```
shortMonths = []
  for M in MONTHS:
    shortmonths.append(M[0:3])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> months = ["January", "Febuary", "March", "April"]
>>> search = "Mar"
>>> [i for i, mo in enumerate(months) if search == mo[0:3]][0]
2
>>> search = "Fan"
>>> [i for i, mo in enumerate(months) if search == mo[0:3]][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy:

```
>>> months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
>>> search = "Jan"
>>> months.index([i for i in months if i[:3].lower() == search.lower()][0])+1
1
>>> # Or
... def getmonth(search):
...    for i in months:
...        if i[:3].lower() == search.lower():
...            return x.index(i)+1
>>> getmonth("Feb")
2
```

To catch the error:

```
months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
while True:
    search = ""
    while len(search) != 3:
        search = raw_input("Enter first 3 letters of a month: ")[:3]
    month = [i for i in months if i[:3].lower() == search.lower()]
    if not month: # Not in the list, empty list: []
        print "%s is not a valid abbreviation!"%search
        continue
    print months.index(month[0])+1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
abbr = raw_input("Enter the month abbr:")


months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
months_abbr = [month.lower()[:3] for month in months]
index = months_abbr.index(abbr.lower())
if index >= 0:
    print "abbr {0} found at index {1}".format(abbr, index)
else:
    print "abbr {0} not found".format(abbr)
```